# How to use same UNNotificationContentExtension with different UNNotificationAction?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uilocalnotification

I want to create UNNotificationContentExtension to show some custom UI. For this, I have to create some category for UNNotificationContentExtension and use it as categoryIdentifier while scheduling notification.
I also want to add some actions with this rich notification, which I have done with

```
let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: notificationContentCategory, actions: [firstAction, secondAction, thirdAction, fourthAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
```

Now the as per new app requirement, These rich notifications should have a different set of actions for different conditions. So as far as I can understand, There is no way to associate **different** set of actions to **same** UNNotificationContentExtension. Is there any way to associate **different** set of actions to **same** UNNotificationContentExtension ?

I am working with local notifications only.

Comment: hi, have you figure out how to do this ? i have the same issue here, thanks

Comment: No. Only solution I know as of now is to create different UNNotificationContentExtension for each set of actions. Please let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution for this. We can add array of identifiers in **UNNotificationExtensionCategory** attribute of info.plist in Notification content extension.
Add all the identifiers here.